# Executing gsutil command in Cloud Run service to sync report to cloud storage

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have a use case where I need to copy reports generated in /tmp or cloud run job to cloud storage -- similar to [Similar Tutorial with Go](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/gcloud) . I am using nodejs to achieve the same and I am getting `/bin/sh: 1: gsutil: not found` when I do `execSync('gsutil cp -r /tmp gs://staging.xxxx-portal.appspot.com');`

My dockerfile is very

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
WORKDIR /app

FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "./index.js"]
```

I am not sure what I am missing to get gsutil command to be executed from nodejs process.

Answer (score 0):

You simply not have `gcloud`, or `gsutil` installed in your container.

Sure, you start with the cloud SDK image, but you do nothing, and you drop it and replace it with the nodejs:14 images.

The `FROM` images are not cumulative.

In your latest `FROM` image, you have to be sure that all the data/binaries are installed. In your case, perform an installation of Cloud SQL in the latest layer of your container.

Comment: Hello @guillaume, Is it possible to forward the cloud sdk after FROM node:14 image optimally ??

Comment: Oh!  You're absolutely right, @guillaume.  I totally missed the `FROM node:14` !

Comment: You can't forward an installation. Install thee CLoud SDK in the NodeJS image!